# How do I use neo4j with Web2py?

Tags: web2py

I am trying to build a very simple Log-in system. For which I am using `neo4j` as the database.

As per the [documentation](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Connection-strings-the-uri-parameter),  I cannot find a way to connect `neo4j` to the DAL.

Should I *manually* connect to `neo4j` and then start a session or is there a way for me to use the DAL (which allows me to easily take care of log-in)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use a particular database with the web2py DAL, there must be an adapter for it, and there is no adapter for Neo4j. web2py's built-in Auth system depends on the DAL, so to use it, you must store at least the Auth related data in one of the databases supported by the DAL. Your options are:

1. Keep everything in Neo4j and therefore do not use web2py's built-in Auth system.
2. Use an alternative database for the Auth data (you can still use Neo4j for everything else), allowing you to use web2py's Auth system.
3. Write your own DAL adapter for Neo4j, as explained [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Note-on-new-DAL-and-adapters).

Comment: Thank you so much for the info, Anthony! Currently what I am doing is: Option 2. 
I keep the main data on neo4j and just the Auth data on MySQL. I'm not *copying* the database, just keeping the Username and Password (bcrypt hash) on MySQL - for the purpose of login. Does this sound alright?
I will also look into writing my own DAL adapter!

Comment: Yes, that seems reasonable.

Comment: I am curious about one more thing - as mentioned above, my passwords are stored as (bcrypt hash). So when I enter a plain-text password and click 'Login', I would like to compute its hash -> check with stored hash. 
The q is: How do I write my *own* login() method to do this? I read that I need to work with auth.login_bare() method, but how would I define it? Thanks!

Comment: web2py can handle that for you. You just need to specify a validator for the password field that does the proper conversion to the hash -- it will be used both to store the password as well as to compare the password submitted at login. Maybe have a look at the implementation of the built-in `CRYPT` validator in gluon.validators. If you need more guidance, post a new question or ask on the Google Group.

Comment: Posted here on SO!